# how to adjust screen brightness after formating laptop?

Tags: windows

i just formatted my laptop and it was all good it was working properly and one day when i tried to adjust screen brightness it was nothing, then i went to power options to adjust but there was no option then i searched on the search box it was showing nothing . i searched this problem on net and came to your website and followed the steps given in one of the answers but it was nothing , now i am trapped help me..

Comment: You probably need to install the manufacturers utility for that. Please [edit] and include the make and model of your laptop and what version of Windows you are using.

Answer (score 0):

This usually occurs because, the VGA drivers are not yet updated. You need to download appropriate drivers from the manufacturer website, alternatively run Windows update (included download drivers option)

The Microsoft Basic VGA drivers (default) have no extended features that control adjustment of  brightness of monitor.

Though I am not pretty sure what you tried that was in solutions, this is usually the starting point. You may need to check system files integrity via `sfc scannow` to further troubleshoot the issue.